# mySQL Query Browser connection using ssh

Tags: mysql, macos, ssh

Does anyone know if there's a problem with the mysql query browser using connections over SSH on the Mac?

I use the command: ssh -L33306:localhost:3306 user@host then I try to open a connection with the MQB pointing it to localhost port 33306

I get an error "Could not connect to MySQL instance at localhost..."

What's odd is that this works fine in Navicat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find "localhost" to be very unreliable on my Mac. Try 127.0.0.1 instead.

Comment: That's nuts...works fine with localhost in one app, needs 127.0.0.1 in another.     Thanks